# Design database using ORM modeller or just Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design, entity-framework-5, entity

As we are starting a new project I am wondering what your take is on how to create/design the database.

Options:

1. Use TOAD for SQl Server to create the entities and generate DDL (SQL) script
2. Use Entity Framework Code First approach where you start with the code
3. ...

My problem with EF code first is that it is hard for me to keep track of changes and actually applying the EF generated migration scripts to the database. Especially in the beginning where changes are anything but rare.

**How do you keep track and apply changes to the model? In other words, how do you keep your EF C# code in sync with the database?**

Comment: More than anything else I found that a good diff tool helps to keep things clear and tidy (but well I suppose there should be a more formal approach).

Comment: Use EF database first and just update your EF model from the database whenever you make changes your schema.  Use SSMS to change your database.  It's better than TOAD and also cheaper.